# Can telnet but nslookup fails

Tags: networking, dns, telnet, hostname, nslookup

The problem is exactly as described in the title... I'm puzzled.

I've seen the opposite many times, but this...

So once again, just to confirm:

```
C:\users\274400>nslookup SERVERNAME
Server:  DNS_SERVERNAME.ad.sys
Address:  00.00.00.00 ( <-- dns ip)

*** DNS_SERVERNAME.ad.sys can't find SERVERNAME: Non-existent domain
```

yet:

```
telnet SERVERNAME 1433
```

works just fine

Other details:

- I have checked spelling. More than tree times
- Ping fails

Comment: Are you sure the hostname is registered with DNS? Also, try `telnet`ting `servername.ad.sys`. `nslookup` queries DNS servers directly and does not use other sources like WINS.

Comment: @DanielB You should post that as an Answer. It's almost certainly correct. nslookup uses DNS only, not /etc/hosts, not WINS, not local broadcast-based NetBIOS Name Service, not LLMNR, not Multicast DNS (a.k.a. mDNS, IETF ZeroConf, Apple Bonjour), not any other possible name->IP resolution service that might be enabled on that PC.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter something like `ping myserver`, the `ping` command has to turn `myserver` into an IP address. To do this, it relies on a so-called “resolver”. Usually, programs on Windows would use the Windows resolver. Microsoft describes its behavior in [KB172218](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172218). (This article is outdated but provides a great overview.)

Sources are queried in the following order until a match is found:

1. Check whether queried name is own host name
2. Look at the [`%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).
3. DNS servers
4. WINS/NetBIOS

Installing additional programs like Bonjour Printer Services for Windows may add additional steps to this order. Depending on who is asking, WINS/NetBIOS may be queried earlier than DNS.

`nslookup`, on the other hand, talks to DNS servers directly and doesn’t use the Windows resolver. That means it cannot resolve NetBIOS names.

Also note that `ping` is blocked in many firewall configurations. However, you can still see whether it successfully resolved the host name to an IP address.